# Retrieve contents of a ZIP file on SharePoint without downloading it

Tags: sharepoint, csom

I have written a bit of automated code that checks a SharePoint site and looks for a ZIP file (lets call it doc.zip).  If doc.zip is found, it downloads it, and then checks for a file (say target.docx).  doc.zip is about 300MB, and so I want to only download where necessary.

What I would like to know is that given SharePoint has some ZIP search capability, is it possible to write code using CSOM (c#) to find doc.zip, and then run some code to retrieve the contents of doc.zip without downloading it.

Just to re-iterate, I am comfortable with searching for files in a folder on SP, downloading the file, and unpacking zip entries.  What I need is to retrieve a ZIP files content on SP without downloading it.

E.g. is there a SP command:

```
cxt.Load(SomeZipFileQuery);
cxt.ExecuteQuery();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: One way would be to add a [custom wcf service](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/24194.sharepoint-2013-create-a-custom-wcf-rest-service-hosted-in-sharepoint-and-deployed-in-a-wsp.aspx) to your sharepoint... You'll then call the service via ajax from the client side...

Answer (score 0):

This capability is not available. I do like the idea. Having the ability to "parse" zip files on the server side and then download the relevant bits would be ideal. Perhaps raise this on uservoice to see if others also find this us https://sharepoint.uservoice.com

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have proven yet again that stubbornness will prevail.

I have figured out that if I use the /_api/search?query='myfile.zip' web REST API to search for my file, this search will also match ZIP files that contain the file I need.  And it works perfectly.

Of course there is added (pain) of parsing an XML response, but it works very nicely for my code example.

At least if someone is looking for this solution here it is.  I wont bore anyone with code, as the /_api/search has probably been done to death already on other threads.